# Select edittexts text in a listview. How can be done? I can't find out

Tags: android, listview, select, android-edittext

I have a ListView with an EditText on each row working.

I need to select this text on click the edittext to write numbers without erasing or moving the cursor.

Using selectAllonfocus at first works. However, after scrolling the listview, the EditText got crazy and selection doesn't work correctly.

If I execute selectAll in the listener onFocus, then when a touch is made the contextmenu (select word, select all,etc) is shown instead of the selection.

If someone can help.

Thanks.

Comment: Workaround: when the listitem is pressed pop up a dialog, this has an edittext, when the dialog is dismissed it populates that row of the listview with the entered text.

Comment: I'm trying to do the same thing and I'm having the same problem...shame you had to go with a dialog, I'd really like to avoid that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I can say about what I asked is that trying to select all text of the listview edittexts don't work properly.
So instead of select the text, I show a dialog where the user selects the number or whatever.

Answer (score 2):

I can't tell what it is that you are trying to do. Perhaps it'd help if you can post some of your relevant source code...

But the fact that it gets crazy when you start scrolling makes me thing you aren't handling the convertView correctly in your adapter getView() method.

Comment: +1 on the convertView suggestion. `selectAllOnFocus` should be the only solution you need, so I'd be interested to see your `getView()` method @Marc.

Answer (score 1):

If you're having problem after scrolling it's the view recycling that's messing you up.  You basically need to set up an array to hold the contents of the EditTexts so when you scroll they don't get messed up.  You didn't say what was backing your list, but I've got a list with edittexts contained and here's how I handle it (from a cursor, but you could adapt it for an ArrayAdapter):

```
public class CursorAdapter_EditText extends SimpleCursorAdapter {

    private static Cursor c;
    private Context context;
    public static String[] quantity;
    private int layout;

    public CursorAdapter_EditText(Context context, int layout, Cursor c,
                        String[] from, int[] to) {
        super(context, layout, c, from, to);
        CursorAdapter_EditText.c = c;
        this.context = context;
        this.layout = layout;
        initializeQuantity();    //  Call method to initialize array to hold edittext info
    }

    public static void initializeQuantity() {
        quantity = new String[c.getCount()];    //  Initialize array to proper # of items
        int i = 0;
        while (i < c.getCount()) {              
                        quantity[i] = "";       // set all EditTexts to empty
                        i++;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null)
                        convertView = View.inflate(context, layout, null);
        final int pos = position;
        View row = convertView;
        c.moveToPosition(position);
        TextView name = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.ListItem1);
        EditText qty = (EditText) row.findViewById(R.id.qty);
        qty.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {  //  Set so EditText will be saved to array when you leave it
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                if (!hasFocus) {
                    LinearLayout parent = (LinearLayout) v.getParent();            
                    EditText qtyTemp = (EditText) parent.findViewById(R.id.qty);   //  Get a reference to EditText (you could probaly use v here)
                    quantity[pos] = qtyTemp.getText().toString();              // Save contents of EditText to array
                }
            }
        });
        name.setText(c.getString(1));
        unit.setText(c.getString(3));
        qty.setText(quantity[position]);
        return (row);
    }
}
```

Then I have a button outside the array that processes it back into my database like this:

```
commit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int i = 0;
        itemCursor.moveToFirst();
        while (itemCursor.isAfterLast() == false) {
            if (CursorAdapter_EditText.quantity[i].equals("")) {
                CursorAdapter_EditText.quantity[i] = "0";
            }
            ;
            int tempQty = Integer
                    .parseInt(CursorAdapter_EditText.quantity[i]);
            if (tempQty != 0) {
                mDbHelper.createListItem(listId, itemCursor
                        .getInt(itemCursor
                                .getColumnIndex(GroceryDB.ITEM_ROWID)),
                        tempQty, 0);
            }
            i++;
            itemCursor.moveToNext();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I'm doing  more or less as you do. No problem with that.
The problem is I need to highlight the text when the edittext got focus, so the user will be able to write directly without delete the content. [https://www.dropbox.com/s/4y4dtxcp3ju0wm/TestListViewEdittext.zip] In the example I execute setSelection when got focus to hightlight. However, if scroll is made on the listview and the rows got off the screen , the hightlight doesn't work well anymore.

Sorry for my English

Comment: The correct link is https://www.dropbox.com/s/4y4dtxcp3ju0wm6/TestListViewEdittext.zip

Answer (score 1):

I dealt with exactly the same problem by doing the following:

1. Remove android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants" from xml with ListView, android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" from AndroidManifest - they ain't help.
2. Subclassed EditText

   ```
   public class TrickyEditText extends EditText {

       private boolean mFocused = false;
       private boolean mTouched = false;

       public TrickyEditText(Context context) {
           super(context);
       }

       public TrickyEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
           super(context, attrs);
       }

       public TrickyEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
           super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
       }

       @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
       public TrickyEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int style) {
           super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, style);
       }

       @Override
       public boolean didTouchFocusSelect() {
           if (mTouched && mFocused) {
               return true;
           } else {
               return super.didTouchFocusSelect();
           }
       }

       @Override
       public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
           mTouched = true;
           return super.onTouchEvent(event);           
       }

       @Override
       protected void onFocusChanged(boolean focused, int direction, Rect previouslyFocusedRect) {
           mFocused = focused;
           if (!focused) {
               mTouched = false;
           }
           super.onFocusChanged(focused, direction, previouslyFocusedRect);
       }
   }
   ```

   3. Adapter code

      ```
      public class TrickyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

          .............

          @Override
          public View getView(int childPosition, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {

              .........

              TrickyEditText et = ..... //initialize edittext

              et.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

                  @Override
                  public void onFocusChange(final View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                      if (hasFocus) {
                          v.post(new Runnable() {

                              @Override
                              public void run() {
                                  ((EditText)v).selectAll();
                              }
                          });                    
                      }
                  }
              });

              .........
          }
      }
      ```

Although it's working pretty well, it's not the code I'm proud of... If somebody knows a prettier solution, please tell me!

Answer (score 1):

On the getView method of your adapter, get your EditView (in this code, edittxt) and do:

```
    edittxt.post(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            edittxt.requestFocusFromTouch();
            edittxt.selectAll();
            InputMethodManager lManager = (InputMethodManager)context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE); 
            lManager.showSoftInput(edittxt, 0);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are still looking for a solution, but I found a way to do it. Add a focus change listener to the edittext in the getView method of your adapter and select all text when focus is received.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = convertView;
    // blah blah blah

    EditText edit = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editTextId);
    edit.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (hasFocus)
                ((EditText) view).selectAll();
        }
    });

    return view;
}
```

I had set windowSoftInputMode to adjustPan for the activity, although I don't think it has any bearing on this matter.

I have tested this on Android 2.3 and 4 and it works.

Comment: This worked for me, thanks a lot. I'm starting to dislike android, it feels buggy and like you need thousands of workarounds to get what you want. At least with ListViews

Comment: Nope, it did not work either: Once in edition mode, everytime you insert a character all the text is again reselected, so it's impossible to write a word with two or more characters.