# EditText Content Changes on ListView Scroll

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I have an Android application with an customized adapter that extends Cursor Adapter.

 I overrided bindView and newview methods of CursorAdapter. Each of my ListView row contains an EditText. When I enter some text in EditText and scrolldown the ListView the content of the EditText text is moved to another EditText. 
Can anyone help me in sorting out this issue to how to prevent EditText from reused its content when ListView is scrolled down.

Thanks in Advance,

Here is the code:

```
        private class AddScreenArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<AddScreenItems>{

  ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
  public String[] holder_values;

public AddScreenArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
        List<AddScreenItems> objects) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
    holder_values = new String[objects.size()];

    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    View v = convertView;
    if (v == null) {
        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = vi.inflate(R.layout.additem_row, null);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.label = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.label_add_item);
        viewHolder.dbName=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.dbtable_name);
        viewHolder.value = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.value_add_item);
        viewHolder.value.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
        {

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                holder_values[viewHolder.ref]= arg0.toString();

            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                    int count, int after) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                    int before, int count) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

        });
        v.setTag(viewHolder);
    }
    else{
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
    }
    AddScreenItems addScreenItems = addScreenItemsList.get(position);
    if(addScreenItems!=null)
    {
        viewHolder.label.setText(addScreenItems.labelname);
        viewHolder.dbName.setText(addScreenItems.databaseTableName);
    //  viewHolder.ref = position;
        if (holder_values[position] != null) 
         { 
            viewHolder.value.setText(holder_values[position]); 
        } 

         else { 
             viewHolder.value.setText(""); 
         }


    }
    return v;


}

    }

             static class ViewHolder {
    public TextView label;
    public EditText value;
    public TextView dbName;
    int ref;
        }
```

Comment: This probably has something to do with the way you're handling view recycling.  Can you post your `getView()` method from the adapter?

Answer (score 0):

If you're having problem after scrolling it's the view recycling that's messing you up. You basically need to set up an array to hold the contents of the EditTexts so when you scroll they don't get messed up.

Here's a link to another answer I gave on  a similar topic.  It ought to point the way for you.  [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10713257/1105376)

**EDIT**

I use `setOnFocusChangeListener` to run code when the user finishes an entry in the EditText box.

```
qty.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
@Override
public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
    if (!hasFocus) {
        LinearLayout parent = (LinearLayout) v.getParent();
        EditText qtyTemp = (EditText) parent.findViewById(R.id.qty);
        quantity[pos] = qtyTemp.getText().toString();
    }
}
});
```

Comment: I updated my code since I used ArrayAdapter instead of Cursor Adapter , but still facing the issue. Can u check my code and help me in solving the issue.

Comment: It looks ok to me.  I've never had much success with TextWatchers, I usually use `setOnFocusChangeListener`, so when the user leaces the edittext box it goes to work.  I'll add a small example to my answer.